# Can I give objdump an address and have it disassemble the containing function?

Tags: c, debugging, disassembly, objdump

I'm finding it really annoying to have to disassemble large swathes of library code just to get enough context to see what is causing a crash. Is there any way that I can just hand objdump an address, and have it find the boundaries of the containing function for me?

EDIT: Better yet, can I have it disassemble an entire stack trace for me?

Comment: Can't you just load the crash core into GDB and explore there? (Or how do you end up with the crash address without using the core or gdb?)

Comment: I'm not sure if the crash is even generating a crash core. This is going towards kernel debugging, and the library that's crashing is doing so really early in the boot process.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Something like this perhaps?

```
$ objdump -S --start-address=0x42 foo.o | awk '{print $0} $3~/retq?/{exit}'
```

It prints the dis-assembly listing starting from `0x42` till it finds a `ret(q)`, assuming the *boundary* is marked by `ret(q)`

Answer (score 4):

**GDB `disassemble`**

```
gdb -batch -ex "file $EXECUTABLE" -ex "disassemble/rs $ADDRESS"
```

For example:

a.c

```
#include <assert.h>

int myfunc(int i) {
    i = i + 2;
    i = i * 2;
    return i;
}

int main(void) {
    assert(myfunc(1) == 6);
    assert(myfunc(2) == 8);
    return 0;
}
```

Compile and disassemble `myfunc` to find an address:

```
gcc -std=c99 -O0 -g a.c
gdb -batch -ex 'file a.out' -ex "disassemble/rs myfunc"
```

Output:

```
Dump of assembler code for function myfunc:
a.c:
3   int myfunc(int i) {
   0x000000000000064a <+0>: 55  push   %rbp
   0x000000000000064b <+1>: 48 89 e5    mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x000000000000064e <+4>: 89 7d fc    mov    %edi,-0x4(%rbp)

4       i = i + 2;
   0x0000000000000651 <+7>: 83 45 fc 02 addl   $0x2,-0x4(%rbp)

5       i = i * 2;
   0x0000000000000655 <+11>:    d1 65 fc    shll   -0x4(%rbp)

6       return i;
   0x0000000000000658 <+14>:    8b 45 fc    mov    -0x4(%rbp),%eax

7   }
   0x000000000000065b <+17>:    5d  pop    %rbp
   0x000000000000065c <+18>:    c3  retq   
End of assembler dump.
```

OK, so 0x0000000000000655 is in `myfunc`, let's confirm it works:

```
gdb -batch -ex 'file a.out' -ex 'disassemble/rs 0x0000000000000655'
```

Output: same as previous disassembly.

See also: [How to disassemble one single function using objdump?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22769246/how-to-disassemble-one-single-function-using-objdump/31138400#31138400)

Tested on Ubuntu 18.04, GDB 8.1.

Answer (score 2):

`objdump --start-address=` perhaps ?