# How can I convert only one file or one function of an elf file to assembly?

Tags: linux-kernel, elf, disassembly

I have an elf file of a very big code base (kernel). I want to convert it to assembly code. I have base address of a function and offset of the instruction. Using this information, I want to get the specific instruction. I have used "`objdump -b binary -m i386 -D file.elf`" to get assembly code from elf file, but it is generating 4GB of data. I have also referred to this [Can I give objdump an address and have it disassemble the containing function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441721/can-i-give-objdump-an-address-and-have-it-disassemble-the-containing-function) but it is also not working for me.

Comment: Why is this tagged linux-kernel?  If what you are attempting to look at is a binary kernel you should say so, and be specific about which format (as it is usually mostly compressed and therefore unintelligible by objdump).  If not, please remove the inapplicable tag.

Answer (score 2):

You can limit `objdump` output with *--start-address* and *--stop-address* options.

For process code only for the single function, values for these options can be taken from `readelf -s` output, which contains start address of the function in the section and the function's size, and from `readelf -S` output, which contains address of the section with the function:

```
--start-address=<section_start + function_start>
--stop-address=<section_start + function_start + function_size>
```

Comment: I tried but I am getting this error :  objdump: --start-address: bad number: ffff000008081891

Comment: Didn't you forget to add `0x` before hexadecimal value?

Comment: yes... after adding 0x it is not giving bad number error... thank you... but now.. I am still not getting output ... this is the command :-  objdump -b binary -m i386 --start-address=0xffff000008081890 --stop-address=0xffff000008081bf4  elf_file and output is elf_file: file format binary

Comment: Make sure that you pass proper *--start-address*. Note, that it should be sum of section's start address (functions are usually contains in `.text` section) and offset of the function within that section (this is what `readelf - s` shows).

Answer (score 0):

> I want to convert it to assembly code.

```
gdb -q ./elf_file
(gdb) set height 0    # prevent pagination
(gdb) set logging on  # output will be mirrored in gdb.txt
(gdb) disassemble 0xffff000008081890 0xffff000008081bf5
(gdb) quit
```

Enjoy!